# Sass change the value of variable based on body class?

Tags: sass, mixins

I am trying to create a sass mixin which allows to redefine the value of a variable according to a class added on . I am stuck at this stage (which does not work) and I wonder if it is finally possible to do so:

```
$color-1: #9E619B;
$color-2: #BB496A;
$themecolor: red !default;
$color-themes: (
   theme1-pages:
       (
           themecolor: $color-1
       )
   theme2-pages:
       (
           themecolor: $color-2
       )
);

@each $name, $theme in $color-themes {
   body.#{$name} {
       $themecolor: map-get ($name, themecolor);
   }
}
```

Comment: First of all,  please remove all spaces beetween `$` & `variable`. Also between hexadecimal colors: `#9E619B`. No space! Then, what is the output you want from that loop? If `$themecolor` is a color => `$themecolor: $color-base !default;`, this rule have no sense for me: `$themecolor: map-get($name, themecolor);`

Comment: Thanks, copy/paste errors

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a syntax error (extra space after `map-get`) and a mistake in the arguments for `map-get()`: the arguments should be `$theme` and `themecolor` respectively, not `$name` and `themecolor`:

```
@each $name, $theme in $color-themes {
   body.#{$name} {
       $themecolor: map-get($theme, themecolor);
   }
}
```

That is because `$name` is simply the key, while `$theme` is the reference to the value. If you paste the fixed version of your code into [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/):

```
$color-1: #9E619B;
$color-2: #BB496A;
$themecolor: red !default;
$color-themes: (
   theme1-pages:
       (
           themecolor: $color-1
       ),
   theme2-pages:
       (
           themecolor: $color-2
       )
);

@each $name, $theme in $color-themes {
   body.#{$name} {
      $themecolor: map-get($theme, themecolor);
      color: $themecolor;
   }
}
```

You should expect to get this back without any error:

```
body.theme1-pages {
  color: #9E619B;
}

body.theme2-pages {
  color: #BB496A;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Terry, you solve syntax problems. But what I would like is change the value of the variable automatically everywhere in the site. For example: h1 {color: $themecolor;} and .inner-bottom-header:before {background-color: $themecolor;} would be compiled into body.theme1-pages h1{color: $color-1;} and body.theme1-pages .inner-bottom-header:before {background-color: $color-1;}

Comment: @user2822813 Then you just nest those rules inside the `@each` loop. There is no way you can globally change the variable.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. I cannot do it this way. Thank you for your help anyway.